# I want to convert col-sm-4 to two equal column(one with image+one with content) and one row at bottom in twitter bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hai I have created three column in one row col-sm-4,col-sm-4,col-sm-4 and every column must be splitt with two equal column and one row at the footer.Like below image,

This is the [sample alignment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrFHz.png)

and my code is ,

```
<div class="container">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;" >
            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_5.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily split it by using new columns inside of columns:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-6"></div> <!-- half column of sm-4 -->
           <div class="col-sm-6"></div> <!-- half column of sm-4 -->
     </div>
</div>
```

In bootstrap, every column you create can be splitted on new `12` columns, but the class `row` is a must.